# regex time extract in list throws Attribute NoneType Error

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract date time from a list

```
jjjj= ['"timeStamp":"2020-03-22T18:03:59Z"',
 '"timeStamp":"2020-03-22T18:04Z"',
 '"timeStamp":"2020-03-22T18:04:01Z"',
 '"timeStamp":"2020-03-22T18:04:02Z"',
 '"timeStamp":"2020-03-22T18:04:03Z"',
 '"timeStamp":"2020-03-22T18:04:04Z"',
 '"timeStamp":"2020-03-22T18:04:05Z"',
 '"timeStamp":"2020-03-22T18:04:06Z"',
 '"timeStamp":"2020-03-22T18:04:07Z"',
 '"timeStamp":"2020-03-22T18:04:08Z"']
```

In following loop if i replace 's' with a string such as "2020-03-22T18:03:59Z" I get the desired result, 
however, if I supply `i[12:].strip()` or `i[12:]` or `str(i[12:])`, I get NoneType error.

```
for i in jjjj:
    import re, datetime
    print(i[12:].strip())
    #s=str(i[12:].strip())

    m = re.match("(\d+)\-(\d+)\-(\d+)\:?(\w+)\:(\d+)\:?(\d+)",s)
    print(m.groups())
    break
```

My desired result is  `('2020', '03', '22', 'T18', '03', '59')`

Error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-a349c8166120> in <module>
      4 
      5     m = re.match("(\d+)\-(\d+)\-(\d+)\:?(\w+)\:(\d+)\:?(\d+)",s)
----> 6     print(m.groups())
      7     break

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Answer
 for i in jjjj:
        import re, datetime
        print(i[12:].strip())
        #s=str(i[12:].strip())

```
    m = re.search("(\d+)\-(\d+)\-(\d+)\:?(\w+)\:(\d+)\:?(\d+)",s)
    print(m.groups())
    break
```

Comment: `re.match` requires a match to be at the string start position, but your `jjj`s all have a `"timeStamp":"` at the start.

Comment: Actually `search` helped. thank you